# $_SESSION variable getting lost somewhere........or PHP ignoring "IF...ELSEIF"

Tags: php, session, if-statement, session-variables, new-window

I am having a problem with getting my PHP script to correctly read and execute my "**IF.....ELSEIF**" conditions.

In my first file, I have the following code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  {

$selected_radio = $_POST['selection'];

$_SESSION['my_selection'] = $_POST['selection'];  

if (($selected_radio == '25')   {

    header("url=http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }

    elseif (($selected_radio == '50')    {

    header("url=http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }
```

}

That was the easy part.

If either "**radio button**" is selected, I have a Javascript function which opens a "**new (child) window**"

That's also easy.

But, then, comes the hard part :  within that new window, the user has to select from another choice of radio buttons :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  {

$selected_radio = $_POST['my_response'];

if (($_POST['my_response'] = 'yes') && ($_SESSION['my_selection'] = '25'))    
{

echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.opener.location =   
 "/PHP/25.php";setTimeout("window.close();", 1000);</script>';
            }

elseif (($_POST['my_response'] = 'yes') && ($_SESSION['my_selection'] =  
'50'))  {

 echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.opener.location = 
 "/PHP/50.php";setTimeout("window.close();", 1000);</script>';
            }
```

Basically, this means :  if the user selects "**yes**" in the current (child) window, then the window closes, and the parent window re-directs to "**25.php**" or "**50.php**"..........depending on the value of the **$_SESSION['my_selection'] --- which was selected earlier in the parent-window**

But, for some reason, it's not working.  My code is executing **only the FIRST  IF-condition :**

```
if (($_POST['my_response'] = 'yes') && ($_SESSION['my_selection'] = '25'))     
{

echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.opener.location = 
"/PHP/25.php";setTimeout("window.close();", 1000);</script>';
            }
```

It is completely ignoring the second one.............even if the user had earlier selected "**50**" in the parent-window.

My first thought was :  the SESSION value of the radio-button ---- **$_SESSION['my_selection']** --- was not being carried-over into the new (child) window.

But, I used "**echo**" to verify that this was working properly.  The value was indeed being carried-over into the new (child) window.

However, after the child-window closes, and the parent-window is re-directed, I used "**echo**" again to track any errors........and it showed that :  the value of **$_SESSION['my_selection']** is always equal to "**25**" !

In a nutshell :  **why is the second IF-statement being ignored??**

```
    elseif (($_POST['my_response'] = 'yes') && ($_SESSION['my_selection'] = 
    '50'))  {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.opener.location =   
    "/PHP/50.php";setTimeout("window.close();", 1000);</script>';
```

Comment: @HarshJoshi It doesn't matter http://php.net/elseif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
($_POST['my_response'] = 'yes') && ($_SESSION['my_selection'] = '25')  
                       ^                                      ^
```

A single equals sign is an assignment and as the value you are assigning is truthy the `if` will always evaluate to `true`. Use `==` for a comparison.

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful response !  :=)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` instead of `==` in nearly all statements:

```
if (($_POST['my_response'] = 'yes')
```

should be

```
if (($_POST['my_response'] == 'yes')
```

This way, you don't check if `$_POST['my_response']` **is equal** to "yes", but if it is possible to assign "yes" to `$_POST['my_response']`. As a result, **all** your `if` statements are `true`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful response !  :=)